# How much Organic Search impacts on sites access

Tags: seo

I was wondering how much does organic searches, on google specially, impacts on visits for a website, in general? I've been looking for some reliable source, with statistics, can't find it, though. I'd like to be able to say "Today, xx% of site visits come from organic searches", with some reference backing the information.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You're never going to get a 100% accurate figure on this.

If you install google analytics on your site, then you'll get pretty accurate figures for google - since they track the click-thrus pretty well on that (altho it requires the client browser to have javascript)>

However, if you wanted to get a 100% accurate you'd need to be checking the click-thrus for every search engine.

One way, however, might be to check the url referrer when a page launches (again, google analytics will do this as well - but there are other solutions that don't rely on Javascript - such as WebTrends).

If it's from a search engine domain - and assuming you haven't got any paid-for adverts on any of them - then they must be from organic searches i would think.

**EDIT: A word of warning**

The most disappointing thing with website searches is that you'll find the top searches will be 'yourdomainname', 'yourdomanenaim' or one of many other mispellings you can think of. Many people simply use google as a replacement for their address bar.

Subsequently you have to clarify exactly what you want 'organic' to mean, and then find a way to trim out any searches that don't fit that.  If this is important to you, then you'd definitely need to be getting your search stats direct from the search engines, and doing some serious pouring over them.

So open those webmaster accounts and getting downloading the csvs!

Comment: You couldnt be more right on the 'yourdomainname' disappointing part! Thank you for your reply